# Visual Studio - Intellisense not recognizing namespace in another project within same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, intellisense

I have a solution consisting of two projects.

The first project is Project.api, while the second is Project.models within C# .NET (webapi) solution. I can not get test.models to be recognized when pointing to it via `using test.models;` at the top of one of my classes.

What do I need to do to get the api project to not show red underline under the .models namespace?

I have tried to re assign asp.net version from 4.5.2 to 4.0, and included references to Project.models under Project.api without success.

How can I get past this intellisense issue?

Please see Solution Explorer screenshot.  Root namespace renamed.

[image: Solution Explorer Screenshot]

Comment: Looking for some guidance, I have posted a general description from my app, omitting some details.  I can post more if needed.

Comment: In Solution Explorer, right click on "References" under Project.api. Pick "Add Reference" on the context menu. In the dialog, click on "Solution" on the tree on the left and find the project you want under Projects. Add a reference to it.

Comment: Just tried it,  all projects are checked, and after rebuild, unfortunately,the red squiggly line remains.

Comment: Did you check the build order? Project.Models should be build first. You can also close Visual Studio and restart. Sometimes things really mess up. I had something similar last week and restarting Visual Studio solved it.

Comment: Perhaps the answers to this question might help http://stackoverflow.com/q/20690470/845655

Comment: Build order was locked and I could not promote/demote project in the list.  @DeanOC, I am looking at your suggestion link.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the References branch of Project.api in Solution Explorer?

Comment: Done, please see screenshot.

Comment: @Vahe Dang, there it is.

Comment: Clearly it is there, but my intellisense only recognizes sw.Data and not the other namespaces.  Admin mode is running, I also tried to open and close solution, unsuccessfully.

Comment: What happens when you try to compile? What error do you get?

Comment: Turns out, with the help of a colleague, my projects had some hidden syntax and type errors I got the issue cleared up.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Can you provide any detail about your solution?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone reading this in 2020, a fix that I've found that has worked for me is cleaning the solution and unloading the projects that have dependencies such as a web API depending on a data project and an application project, then reloading and building each project in the order of dependence such that they build successfully.

Unloading projects: right click on the project in solution explorer and find "Unload Project"

Reloading Projects: right click on the unloaded project in solution explorer and find "Reload Project"

so in my case my data project does not depend on any other project so I first reloaded and built that project, next the application project which depends on the data project and finally the web API project which depended on both data and application.

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me is to delete all the `bin` and `obj` folders from all the projects in a solution. I'm not 100% sure, but I think that visual studio caches stuff in obj folders and then might take something from there and even rebuild doesn't help as cleaning deletes only `bin` folder, but doesn't touch `obj`.